# Select rows of every specific number of col where values is negative and convert values 0 in another column in python3

Tags: python-3.x

i have below dataframe

```
date                  B         C         D         E
2019-07-01 00:00   0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558
2019-07-01 00:10   -0.950088 0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599
2019-07-01 00:20   1.454274  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
2019-07-01 00:30   -1.494079 0.205158  0.313068  0.854096
```

suppose every even columns of rows contains -ve values(may be multiple condition,ex. rows contains -ve value or more than 10) then i wants to next odd column values into 0

expected output

```
date                  B         C         D         E
2019-07-01 00:00   0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558
2019-07-01 00:10   -0.950088     0    -0.103219     0
2019-07-01 00:20   1.454274  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
2019-07-01 00:30   -1.494079     0     0.313068  0.854096
```

if code one liner solution is then its best or can we write function for this

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires the `date` column to be set as the index:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df[df.shift(axis=1) < 0] = 0
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

`df.shift` returns a new dataframe with all the columns shifted to the right (default behaviour; can be changed using the `periods` parameter). This enables you to compare a cell with one to its left.

**Source**: [DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)